# Why when I implement a lambda expression in the main method, the compiler doesn't say the interfaces are implemented?

Tags: java, lambda, interface, interface-implementation

When I implement interfaces as a Lambda expression in my main method, it doesn't count as if it was implemented.

I know I can implement it outside of the main method, but I don't see why I should use Lambda expressions if I have to implement it outside of the main anyway.

```
public class Driver implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Implementing Interface1
        double x;
        Interface1 obj = () -> 5.5;
        x = obj.foo();
        System.out.println(x);

        //Implementing Interface2
        String str;
        Interface2 obj2 = (a) -> String.format("The number is %d", a);
        str = obj2.foo(356);
        System.out.println(str);

        //Implementing Interface3

        boolean tF;
        Interface3 obj3 = (i, s) -> i == Integer.parseInt(s);


        tF = obj3.foo(30, "30");
        System.out.print(tF);

    }
```

Here, I get an error message at line 1 telling me that the Interfaces are not implemented. It still compiles and works, I just don't understand why I get this message.
The output is currently:

```
5.5
The number is 356
true
```

Comment: what's wrong with above code?

Comment: @Deadpool I get a message from the compiler telling me that the Interfaces are not implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have done is define *local variables* in the main method whose type happens to coincide with the interfaces that the *class* must implement.

You must define *methods* in the class that provide implementations for all the interfaces of the class. For example:

```
public class Driver implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // all code in here is irrelevant to the class implementing Interface1, Interface2, Interface3
    }

    public void interface1Method() {
        // whatever
    }

    public void interface2Method() {
        // whatever
    }

    public void interface3Method() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Note that you can't use lambdas for this; `Driver` must actually declare implementations for the missing methods from all the interfaces its declares it is implementing.

Comment: Or remove the `implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3` from the `Driver` class.